# Merge query optimization Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create a relationship between 2 nodes where there are only a few unique pairs and all the others may get repeated. Probably, because of only a few unique nodes, the import-tool is not able to create a relationship, however, when I run a query for the relationship creation in a shell it takes too long. How can I optimize this query by some kind of filtering for uniqueness?

```
MATCH (a:Applications), (sms:Sms {id: a.application_id})
MERGE (a)-[r:APP_SMS]->(sms)
RETURN distinct a.application_id, sms.id
```

I have only found a possibility to use distinct in a return part of the query.

I have executed the same query with profile and limit 25 to see the query plan and results:

```
10382692 total db hits in 3219 ms
```

[image: query plan]

Comment: Run a PROFILE on the query and add the query plan (with all elements expanded) to your question.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I have updated the question with the query plan

Comment: @Cassie How about adding an index `:Sms(id)`? https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/#schema-index-create-a-single-property-index // And add the condition `WHERE NOT (a)-[r:APP_SMS]->(sms)`?

Answer (score 1):

As `stdob--` suggested, you need to create an index on :Sms(id) so this becomes a cheap NodeByIndexSeek instead of NodeByLabelScan for the `sms` node.

That you only have 25 rows after the DISTINCT operation is a little concerning, as `id` fields tend to suggest uniqueness for nodes in a label, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. For the nodes which have the same `id` property, are these duplicate nodes, with the same properties, or are the other properties aside from `id` different? If you have duplicate nodes in the db that that suggests a modeling problem.

EDIT

Per the comments, you added a LIMIT 25 to the query so the DISTINCT 25 results makes sense.

There shouldn't be a duplication issue here, unless `id` isn't unique across :Sms nodes.

Not sure if there's much that can be optimized. You could try batching the MERGE of the relationship using [apoc.periodic.iterate()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_iterate), but you should do that without parallelization to avoid locking issues.

Comment: It`s just there is a one-to-many relationship from Applications to Sms entity. That's why application_id field can be repeated

Comment: I understand the one-to-many relationships, however that should be included when we do `RETURN distinct a.application_id, sms.id`, which yields 25 rows. That we have so many rows before the DISTINCT operation is a red flag to me, that suggests that there are many duplicate nodes of one (or both) labels for the same id, which may not be intended in your model. Alternately (or in addition), it could indicate that there are multiple `:APP_SMS` relationships between the same pairings of :Applications and :Sms.

Comment: 25 rows are displayed in the end just because I've limited this query to 25 results in order to make it run faster. In the end, it's supposed to be more rows than 25

Comment: Ah, right, there's the LIMIT operator. It wasn't present in the query itself (and I jumped in before your remark on it in the description) so I overlooked it.